# javascript_include_tag generating extra HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my manifest file I have the following:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and my inclusion is pretty standard:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

But for some reason, this is the output:

```
<script src="
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/landf/assets/application-f197c043b1bf438ab7beaa68751618f6.js"></script>
```

Anyone have an idea why it's doing this? As far as I can tell, I'm following the docs just fine. Thanks for any help!

### Update

It looks like if I put that tag in the `<head>` there isn't an issue, but placing it right before `</body>` causes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a method I was running a different asset through that was causing the initial script src to be corrupted, causing the collision of multiple script tags.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can place your javascript tag at the end of the file below body tag, it wil load faster. Check if placing it below doesn't cause the issue

Comment: That's exactly the problem - when I place `<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>` right before `</body>` it causes the actual output to corrupt. Please re-read my original issue.